# How to send a "Put" request with a JSON object to a JSONPlaceHolder REST API in Java

Tags: java, json

I currently have code that pulls down all the information from the JSONPlaceHolder REST API and parses it into an array.  I then have code that takes input from text fields in my program and then creates a JSON Object with that information.  I would now like to take that JSON Object and send it to the JSONPlaceHolder REST API that I have set up.  Here is the code that I tried to use but it doesn't like passing the JSON Object as the parameter.  I get the error: "Cannot resolve method 'write(org.json.JSONObject)'."  I've looked at other questions similar to this on Stack Overflow but none of them are sending a JSON Object.  Here is the code I currently have.

```
public static void makePost(JSONObject o) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("https://marketplace-7a251.firebaseio.com/Postings.json");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("Put");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                conn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(o);             //This is where the problem is
        out.close();
        conn.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
This is the error I get now that I changed o to o.toString() in the write method.

```
    java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: Put
{"Category":"Textbooks","Description":"I like math.","Price":"10","Title":"Math Book","id":"test@test.com"}
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:552)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
    at view.Main.makePost(Main.java:122)
    at view.MarketplaceController.createPostButtonClicked(MarketplaceController.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: "_but it doesn't like passing the JSON Object as the parameter_" You need to tell us what _exactly_ is going wrong or what _exact_ error message you get. "it doesn't like..." is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: Sorry, "Cannot resolve method 'write(org.json.JSONObject)'"

Comment: Well, I read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write(char[],%20int,%20int)) and the `write` method of the `OutputStreamWriter` class only takes either a `String`, `char[]`, or `int` so I'm not sure why you expected the above code to work. To use that method you will need to convert your JSONObject into one of those data types.

Comment: Do you know of any method that would take a JSON Object?  That is more what I was aiming for.  I couldn't find any and if I have to I can make it into a string but I feel like there should be a way to send a JSON Object.

Comment: I changed it to be o.toString() in the write method but now am getting the error that I added to the main question.

Comment: Maybe you can cleanup the long trace log to make your question more readable

Comment: @amf812 **Did it worked?** Can you please accept and maybe upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0):

`setRequestMethod(String method)` appear to need an UPPERCASE string method name.

So you can try with `conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");`